# Python try except instruction not work as wanted

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying the try except way and in particular I want to execute the `pass` instruction when there is no item, but the `pass` instruction raise an error.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
    try:
        scamframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='scmframe']")))
        driver.switch_to.frame(scamframe)
        contentfra = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "content")))
        driver.switch_to.frame(contentfra)
        commentframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "search-editor")))
        driver.switch_to.frame(commentframe)
    
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div/div/c-wiz/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/textarea'))).send_keys("New Search")
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/c-wiz[1]/div[1]/div[1]/c-wiz[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/span[1]")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'kSalih001'", element)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"kSalih001")]'))).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        try:
            link = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@id='search-editor-src']")))
            print(link.get_attribute('href'))
            driver.get(link.get_attribute('href'))
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
            print('Element Not Found!')
            driver.quit()
            os._exit(0)
```

Someone can help me to find the error?

ERROR OUTPUT:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kSalih\Desktop\ADV Blog\CookieYok.py", line 255, in <module>
    cookie_yok(desktop + '\StepBlog//Config//allproxy.txt', firstLineprox)
  File "c:\Users\kSalih\Desktop\ADV Blog\CookieYok.py", line 236, in cookie_yok
    commentframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "search-editor")))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kSalih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00C8ACD3+2075859]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C1EE61+1633889]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B1B7BD+571325]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B4AC2F+764975]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B4AE1B+765467]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B7D0F2+970994]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B67364+881508]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B7B56A+963946]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B67136+880950]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B3FEFD+720637]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B40F3F+724799]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F3EED2+2769538]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F30D95+2711877]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D1A03A+521194]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D18DA0+516432]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C2682C+1665068]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C2B128+1683752]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C2B215+1683989]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C36484+1729668]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7749FEF9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E57BBE+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E57B8E+238]

Exception ignored in: <function Chrome.__del__ at 0x0000021B810AF880>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kSalih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 657, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\kSalih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 645, in quit
OSError: [WinError 6] İşleyici geçersiz
Exception ignored in: <function Patcher.__del__ at 0x0000021B81048A40>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kSalih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 273, in __del__
OSError: [WinError 6] İşleyici geçersiz
```

Comment: In your code the `pass` instruction is executed when there aren't items and after it will be executed the instruction `print('Element Not Found!')` so appears the message error `Element Not Found`.

Comment: The program gives an error before coming to the pass part because the element was not found

Comment: So what is exactly the output of the code execution? The instruction `print(link.get_attribute('href'))` is executed or not? Have you add to your program the following: `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`

Comment: print(link.get_attribute('href')) 
it does not execute this code, it gives an error that the element could not be found above, yes I added the codes you wrote

Comment: So if I have understood the your code executes the instruction `print('Element Not Found!')` and after exit as effect of the  execution of `os._exit(0)`?

Comment: yes, but it crashes and closes before I get to that section.

Comment: It doesn't crash it executes the instruction `os._exit(0)`. I think that every times your code executes the instruction `WebDriverWait()` it raises the exception `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\kSalih\Desktop\ADV Blog\CookieYok.py", line 255, in <module>
cookie_yok(desktop + '\StepBlog//Config//allproxy.txt', firstLineprox)
File "c:\Users\kSalih\Desktop\ADV Blog\CookieYok.py", line 236, in cookie_yok
commentframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "search-editor")))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: So your program isn't catch the exception `NoSuchElementException` but it is raising an other exception. Please add the all the output of you code execution to your question.

Comment: I added the output message

Comment: You only handled NoSuchElementException. The exception clearly states it's a TimeoutException. You have no exception defined for it so it just raises one from Selenium.

Comment: @misantroop I agree with you

Comment: Do I need to add TimeoutException, except?

try:

except TimeoutException: ?

Comment: @MartinBie Yes, you need to handle exceptions properly. You can also catch multiple at once e.g. except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as exc.